# Is there a way to get [resetFilterOnHide]="true" on p-dropdown to work with primeng 5.2.7?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

The [resetFilterOnHide]="true" on p-dropdown does not work. If I type in the filter bar, click outside of the dropdown to close it, and then enter the dropdown again, the filter I entered is still there.

I am using primeng 5.2.7 in an angular 4 application. Unfortately I cannot upgarde these to the latest versions because of which I am facing some issues with the p-dropdown component of primeng. The issue is documented and fixed in primeng 6.0.1 according to https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5915.

Is there a way to fix this in primeng 5.2.7?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override `bindDocumentClickListener()` method form primeng Dropdown and make the same change as it is in: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/bbd66dfd15275761be9aa3e757825d32f0f6f531

This should like:

```
Dropdown.prototype.bindDocumentClickListener = function() {
    if(!this.documentClickListener) {
        this.documentClickListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', () => {
            if(!this.selfClick&&!this.itemClick) {
                this.hide();
                this.unbindDocumentClickListener();
            }

            this.selfClick = false;
            this.itemClick = false;
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        });
    }
}
```

But you should also check if `hide()` method exists for primeng version which you are using in Dropdown component.